# Mismatching Conda and Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pytorch

I'm new in python and I'm confused about  mismatching Conda packages list and Pycharm. In a project I need to install pytorch. Installing with pycharm lead to some error and when I install it through conda, It does not appear in pycharm. Both list is the same env.

Thanks in advance.

pycharm list
[image: pycharm list]

Anaconda list
[image: anaconda list]

Comment: my recommendation: never install anything through pycharm. use conda as much as possible, and only fall back to pip when you *really* have to. you've got two scikit-learns installed (one is for python3.7!) and that's not gonna be good for business.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm shows you the list of installed packages with `pip`, while `conda list` shows both `pip` and `conda`. Meanwhile, you can switch between `pip` and `conda` with a dedicated button in PyCharm:

[image]